# ITunes Connect/Testflight - The request app is not available or does not exist

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

I just moved from distributing beta versions of my iOS app through testflightapp.com to the TestFlight service baked into iTunes Connect.

Some external testers (not tried internal) are having no problem, some are getting this message when they click the invite email link:

[image: Testflight app error]

The user has:

- Fully updated the iPad. (Version 8.1.2)
- Fully updated Testflight app from the app store. (Version 8.1.2)

The email address I'm inviting is different from the Apple Id but I thought this was not a problem.

Comment: Same problem here. works on one iPad but not on other. Anybody able to solve this issue ?

Comment: So we have a feeling that the problem was the network they were trying to install it on was heavily locked down (a primary school). We think it is blocking SSL connections and therefore cannot connect to the Apple authentication server. It worked fine when we brought the same iPad back to the office and tried it on a network we knew. I'm still not sure why we get this message though. Hope this helps.

Comment: any updates on this issue?

Comment: No sorry I just put the app on the devices they had locally. We are still looking to solve the problem and distribute using the iTunes Connect method. I will update if I find out anything more.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you do not reuse same email for a different device. I was getting this error trying to reuse invitation on another ipad after installing it on another ipad. Once I registered new user with another email, I was able to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask the admin of an iTunesConnect to remove and add to the list of beta testers, so you will receive a new invitation and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this too. In my case it helps to disable the build and then re-enabled it again.

Cheers

/Edward.

Answer (score 0):

Found this by Lefteris - worked for my me:

> Make sure that you are logged in with the correct iTunes account on
>   the device, as it will not show the app if you are using a different
>   iTunes account from the one specified in the iTunes Connect private
>   beta

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476913/cant-open-testflight-build#30477380)