# Can't open testflight build

Tags: ios, testflight

Now when I open testflight link on iPhone I get an error:
"The requested app is not available or doesn't exist." Earlier everything was ok. How to resolve this issue?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Testflight apps expire after 28 days. Check with the developer of the app.

Comment: It's a new build 1-2 days old.

Comment: Is this a private test release or public beta?

Comment: It's private test for internal testers.

Comment: Had the same problem yesterday, I deleted the affected tester accounts and invited them again.

Comment: @matthias yes you are right, you can answer question and I will choose your answer as best answer.

Comment: the user getting this problem is the admin(Owner) of the account. I have disabled and re-Enabled the build for testing, still not solved. Also deleted that user as internal tester and added once again, No success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(See comments on question)

I had the same problem yesterday. The only working solution was to delete the affected tester accounts from iTunesConnect and to invite them (and add them as internal testers) again.

Comment: Same issue here. But this is our admin account. I don't think we can delete it. Hoping to find an alternative.

Comment: Same issue here, on admin account, so created a new account, same issue, deleted that account, same issue.  It sends testflight notifications to the user, but can't download it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are logged in with the correct iTunes account on the device, as it will not show the app if you are using a different iTunes account from the one specified in the iTunes Connect private beta

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my problem.

- log into itunes Connect
- on itunes connect user, click +
- I created a new user (same email but with + portion) ie user+testing@gmail.com
- Give them a role that includes In-App Purchase Tester
- make sure to add them to a group (this is the thing I missed)
- verify from the apple id email for that user
- create apple id account
- back in itunes connect click on My Apps
- click on prerelease
- click on internal testers
- make sure they have a check in the check box, click save
- click on Builds
- click on Testers
- make sure they exist in the list of testers now
- I then turned off the beta test for that build, and then reenabled the testflight beta testing, so that it resends the notification